# ffmpeg input stream failover

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

Is there a way in ffmpeg to start a secondary input stream immediately in case of the main input stream drops or got some error

Something like

```
ffmpeg -i http://main.server/stream/vid.m3u8 -i 
http://backup.server/stream/vid.m3u8 -c:a copy -c:v copy -f mpegts 
rtmp://output.server/stream
```

or any other ways or workarounds

Comment: Is the backup stream guaranteed to be up?

Comment: @Mulvya yes but at sometimes it may go off so I want to setup a failover secondary input

Comment: Hi @Mas, where you able to figure it out?

Comment: Hi @Nick just used server side solutions like re-opening the process after it stopped mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730644/ffmpeg-how-to-keep-udp-stream-connection-open-even-source-drop-some-minute?rq=1   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730644/ffmpeg-how-to-keep-udp-stream-connection-open-even-source-drop-some-minute?rq=1

Comment: Hi @Mas, thank you! I just implemented it. Way better than running a cron job every minute to check the status of FFmpeg